# amCharts show value change in rollover balloon

Tags: javascript, amcharts

There is a problem the implementation of obtaining the previous value. For example:

```
[ {
  "date": "2009-09-1",
  "test": 100,
  "test2": 900
}, {
  "date": "2009-09-2",
  "test": 200,
  "test2": 800
}, {
  "date": "2009-09-3",
  "test": 300,
  "test2": 700
}, {
  "date": "2009-09-4",
  "test": 400,
  "test2": 600
}, {
  "date": "2009-09-5",
  "test": 500,
  "test2": 500
} ]
```

There are some data that I need to get the value of each point of the previous one, subtract from the current value or increase. For example, in the 'test' 2009-09-2 suggests I should show the "test: 200 (+100)" and 'test2' 2009-09-4 "test2: 600 (-100)"

In the examples on site do not find solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltv1yLn3/2/

```
var chartData = [{"date":"2009-09-1","test":100, "test2": 900}, {"date":"2009-09-2","test":200, "test2": 800}, {"date":"2009-09-3","test":300, "test2": 700}, {"date":"2009-09-4","test":400, "test2": 600}, {"date":"2009-09-5","test":500, "test2": 500}];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",

    "legend": {
        "useGraphSettings": true,
        "align": "center",
        "valueAlign": "left",
        "valueText": "[[value]] ([[percents]]%)"
    },
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "graphs": [
        {
            "lineColor": "#000000",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
            "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "bulletSize": 3,
            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
            "title": "Test 1",
            "valueField": "test",
            "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]] (-+100)"
        },
        {
            "lineColor": "#111111",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
            "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "bulletSize": 3,
            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
            "title": "Test 2",
            "valueField": "test2","balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]] (-+100)"
        },
    ],
    "chartCursor": {
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "fullWidth": true,
        "cursorAlpha": 0.05
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use graph's [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction) to automatically calculate the change.

I.e.:

```
"graphs": [ {
  // ...
  "balloonText": "[[title]]",
  "balloonFunction": balloonFunction
}, {
  // ...
  "balloonText": "[[title]]",
  "balloonFunction": balloonFunction
} ]
```

The working `balloonFunction` is this:

```
function balloonFunction( item, graph ) {
  // init variables
  var chart = graph.chart;
  var key = graph.valueField;
  var data = chart.dataProvider;
  var text = graph.title + ": " + data[ item.index ][ key ];

  // add change if it's not the first item
  if ( item.index ) {
    var change = data[ item.index ][ key ] - data[ item.index - 1 ][ key ]
    var sign = change > 0 ? "+" : "";
    text += " (" + sign + change + ")";
  }
  return text;
}
```

And here's your updated fiddle with the above:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltv1yLn3/3/

P.S. please note, that even though we're using `balloonFunction` to format balloon contents, the `balloonText` is still needed, because without it `balloonFunction` is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom baloon function instead of `baloonText`:

```
function adjustBalloonText(graphDataItem, graph){
    var currentValue = graphDataItem.values.value;
    var previousValue = // calculate it somehow (probably by searching in the original data source)
    return currentValue + " (" + previousValue + ")";
}
```

See http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/updating-balloon-tool-tip-text-fly/